# Django get_rss template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use get_rss template tag in Django.
The following code works for me:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
    {% get_rss "http://rss-url" as rss %}
    {% for entry in rss %}
        {% include "rss.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but when i try to substitute with variable it doesn't output anything:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
    {% get_rss "{{ feed }}" as rss %}
    {% for entry in rss %}
        {% include "rss.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there workaround for it?

Comment: did you try {% get_rss feed as rss %}?  My read of django templates says that should work (note the no quotes around feed)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I edited the example.

Comment: just check if ``{{ feed }}`` has really something in it.

Comment: 'feed' is not empty and contains the string.

Comment: @mirt try this: ``{% get_rss feed as rss %}``.

Comment: As i said before it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving in string inside string. try this

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
 {% if feed %}
  {% get_rss feed as rss %}
  {% for entry in rss %}
    {% include "rss.html" %}
  {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```